# In C#, how do you check if a path is virtual or not?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, path

Possible virtual paths:

```
/folder1/folder2/image.jpg
~/folder1/folder2/image.jpg
folder1/folder2/image.jpg
```

Concrete path:

```
C:\folder1\folder2\image.jpg
D:\folder1\folder2\image.jpg
C:/folder1/folder2/image.jpg
C:/folder1\folder2/image.jpg
```

How do you check whether a path is virtual or not in a way that's not prone to failure? The reason why I'm asking is because when I use `Server.MapPath()` on a concrete path, it will throw an exception. However, what I'm passing to `Server.MapPath()` can be any one of the examples I provided above and I don't know what it is before run-time.

Comment: Can't you check if it starts with `X:` ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This works well enough for me:

```
protected string GetPath(string path)
{
    if (Path.IsPathRooted(path))
    {
        return path;
    }

    return Server.MapPath(path);
}
```

Comment: This wont work for `/folder1/folder2/image.jpg` which will return `true`

Comment: Downvoted because `Path.IsPathRooted("/folder1/folder2/image.jpg");`  returns `true` and it should have instead returned `false`;

Comment: This will work in 'some' cases, but will fail for paths starting with "/".

Comment: what about adding a `path.TrimStart('\\', '/')` before the check?

Answer (score 8):

Would `Path.GetFullPath(string path)` fit your needs? You could use that method then compare if the path changed.

```
if (path == Path.GetFullPath(path))
{
    // This is the full path (no changes)
}
else
{
    // This is not the full path i.e. 'virtual' (changes)
}
```

**Reference:**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx

Comment: i am new here and how can i cancel my operation?

Answer (score 1):

I would use Reflector to check what `Server.MapPath()` does and do that. :)

An alternative might be `System.IO.Path.GetPathRoot()` - if it returns `null` then it's a relative path. This is a little bit of a hack, though, since it doesn't know anything about web paths, so if it's works it would work by coincidence.

Answer (score 1):

> The reason why I'm asking is because when I use Server.MapPath() on a concrete path, it will throw an exception

Does it throw a specific exception for this type of condition, or does it throw a generic one? If the exception is specific to the condition that the input path was concrete, I would catch that specific exception in your code. Even if it's a generic exception, I would still catch this exception, you may not be able to decode if it was thrown because the input path was virtual, but you can at least write your own exception message including a notice that it *could* be caused by the input path being virtual.

I believe this is the least error prone solution because you rely on the implementation of Server.MapPath() to determine the conditions under which it fails, instead of trying to create a redundant wrapper that is trying to do the same thing. In the future the functionality of MapPath() may change and it may actually start supporting virtual paths, then it would be silly that you have code to actually prevent that use.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex...

```
^(?:[a-zA-Z]:(?:\\|/)|\\\\)
```

If you want to ensure that you always have a mapped path. You can use the following one-liner...

VB.Net

```
my_path = If(Regex.IsMatch(my_path, "^(?:[a-zA-Z]:(?:\\|/)|\\\\)"), my_path, Server.MapPath(my_path))
```

C#

```
my_path = Regex.IsMatch(my_path, @"^(?:[a-zA-Z]:(?:\\|/)|\\\\)") ? my_path : Server.MapPath(my_path);
```

This should work correctly with regular drive paths "c:\", as well as UNC paths "\\".

Answer (score 0):

// Path.IsPathRooted("/folder1/folder2/image.jpg");  returns true

```
 public void Main()
        {
            var path = @"/folder1/folder2/image.jpg";
            //is valid path?
            if (!System.IO.Path.GetInvalidPathChars().Any(c => path.Contains(c.ToString())))
            {

                if (IsAbsolutePhysicalPath(path))
                {
                    // This is the full path
                }
                else
                {
                    // This is not the full path
                }

            }
        }
        private bool IsAbsolutePhysicalPath(string path)
        {
            if (path == null || path.Length < 3)
                return false;

            // e.g c:\foo
            if (path[1] == ':' && IsDirectorySeparatorChar(path[2]))
                return true;

            // e.g \\server\share\foo or //server/share/foo
            return IsUncSharePath(path);
        }
        private bool IsDirectorySeparatorChar(char ch)
        {
            return (ch == '\\' || ch == '/');
        }

        private bool IsUncSharePath(string path)
        {
            // e.g \\server\share\foo or //server/share/foo
            if (path.Length > 2 && IsDirectorySeparatorChar(path[0]) && IsDirectorySeparatorChar(path[1]))
                return true;
            return false;

        }
```

**Reference:**
http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/Util/UrlPath.cs,5e5cf20a50a858e2

Comment: This can be accomplished much more easily with a regular expression. A regex can do exactly the same thing in 1 line.